# ¿Como puedo implementar lo siguiente en Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Necesito implementar la siguiente lista, pero no se como realizarla utilizando Bootstrap.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Un ejemplo en bootstrap podría ser el siguiente, en el que se ajusta bastante a lo que pides:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div><p>Tus BlaBlaCarrus activos:</p></div>
            <div class="row border border-dark">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <strong>Ficzone Granada</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <p class="m-0"><strong>Día de ida:</strong> 28 de marzo</p>
                    <p class="m-0"><strong>Hora:</strong> 10:30</p>
                    <p class="m-0"><strong>Lugar:</strong> Jaén, Centro la loma</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm">
                    <p class="m-0"><strong>Día de ida:</strong> 28 de marzo</p>
                    <p class="m-0"><strong>Hora:</strong> 21:30</p>
                    <p class="m-0"><strong>Lugar:</strong> Granada, Fermasa</p>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</html>
```

Para hacer los grid necesitas usar `row` y `col-sm` donde `sm` es el tamaño deseado, donde para este ejemplo es perfecto.

En la [documentación de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) puedes echarle un ojo a una información y ejemplos más amplios.

Answer (score -1):

Así amigo, lee un poco la documentación de bootstrap, te ayudará mucho

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div style="background-color: gray; border: 1px solid black;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"><strong>Ficzone</strong> Granada</div>
    <div class="col-4"><strong>Día...:</strong> 28 de marzo</div>
    <div class="col-4"><strong>Día...:</strong> 28 de marzo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4"><strong>hora:</strong> 10</div>
    <div class="col-4"><strong>hora:</strong> 21</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4"><strong>Lugar:</strong> Jaén</div>
    <div class="col-4"><strong>Lugar:</strong> granada</div>
  </div>
</div>
```